# Calling different dialog activity to different infoWindow click event

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, customdialog

I'm currently making a Campus Map using Google Maps API v2.
I have currently 10 map markers. Each of them has its info Window.
What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on the info Window, it shows a Listview Custom Dialog. I wanna use the if else statement but I don't know how to construct since I haven't found any examples on the Internet.

This is my Dialog Activity

```
public class AdminDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.layers)
           .setItems(R.array.layer_options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
    }
```

And I have some sample markers...

```
public void addMarkersToMap() {
  Marker cmumarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(cmu)
   .title("Central Mindanao University")
   .snippet("Population: 6,143"));
   cmumarker.showInfoWindow();

  Marker adminmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(admin)
    .title("Central Mindanao University Administration Building")
    .snippet("Population: 1,234")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

  Marker casmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(cas)
    .title("College of Arts and Sciences")
    .snippet("Population: 1,234")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
}
```

My concern is how to construct an if else statement or a switch case statement using this code.. this is where the Custom Dialog is called..

```
adminDialog = new AdminDialog();
adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. declare your markers as fields, instead of local varaibles

   ```
   Marker cmumarker , adminmarker, casmarker;
   // You can also keep the ids
   String cmumarkerId , adminmarkerId, casmarkerID;
   public void addMarkersToMap() {
     cmumarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(cmu)
    .title("Central Mindanao University")
    .snippet("Population: 6,143"));
    cmumarker.showInfoWindow();
    cmumarkerId=cmumarker.getID();

    adminmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(admin)
     .title("Central Mindanao University Administration Building")
     .snippet("Population: 1,234")
     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    adminmarkerId=adminmarker.getID();

    casmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(cas)
     .title("College of Arts and Sciences")
     .snippet("Population: 1,234")
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    casmarkerId=casmarker.getID();
   }
   ```
2. set the click listener to the markers, for example after you create the map, or at the end of `addMarkersToMap()`

   ```
   map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
   ```
3. override the   `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)`  function, and make your decisions

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {



           if (marker.getId().equals(cmumarkerId)) {
               //do whatever you want 
               return true;
           }

           if (marker.getId().equals(adminmarkerId)) {
                //do whatever you want                  
                return true;
           }
           if (marker.getId().equals(casmarkerId)) {
               //do whatever you want                  
               return true;
           }

         return false;
   }
   ```

Also, if you want the info window to be clicable, instead of the marker, you

- overrride the `public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)` instead of the onMarkerClick
- asign the listener by means of `map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);` instead of map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

UPDATE:

If you have many markers, you can look for a better way of keeping the ids. Some people uses to compare directly the marker, by reference(ie. if (marker==adminmarker{...}) but sometimes it happens to be diferent objects with the same values, so the id is the most secure way of comparing them.

Comment: I'm using the onInfoWindowClick because I want the infoWindow to be clickable and the one to call the custom dialog..

Comment: @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
  AdminDialog adminDialog;
  
   if (marker == cmumarker) {
    
      }

   if (marker == adminmarker) {
    adminDialog = new AdminDialog();
     adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");                 
      }
   
   if (marker == casmarker) {
          //do whatever you want                  
      }  
  } This.. it does nothing..

Comment: you are doing map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);? is the function  onInfoWindowClick actually called? (did you put a breakpoint, a Log, or a toast to check what code is executed?)

Comment: yes i am doing infoWindow.. if else does really do nothing in my case.. In my infoWindow, I'm calling another activity, which is the custom dialog..

Comment: @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker adminmarker) {
  AdminDialog adminDialog;
 
    adminDialog = new AdminDialog();
     adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");                  
  } this code worked but it can be opened by all the infoWindow, when instead I just want the adminmarker to open this activity..

Comment: give me a second, probably you have to compare marker.getID(), let me check some of my code and i will be back

Comment: im afraid to say that it is supposed to work just comparing the references. I will update the code with an extra test

Comment: Try with that 2 Toast in the code to check if the markers are the same

Comment: can I use that for the infoWindow?

Comment: How do I use this? It says Info Window clicked@m1 .. they don't have the same numbers though.. ^_^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44578/discussion-between-carlos-robles-and-banananadss)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for the answers.. **Credits to Carlos Robles**..

```
Marker cmumarker, adminmarker, casmarker;
String PREVIOUS_ID;

public void addMarkersToMap() {
cmumarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(cmu)
.title("Central Mindanao University")
.snippet("Population: 6,143"));
cmumarker.showInfoWindow();

adminmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(admin)
.title("Central Mindanao University Administration Building")
.snippet("Population: 1,234")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

casmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(cas)
.title("College of Arts and Sciences")
.snippet("Population: 1,234")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

PREVIOUS_ID=adminmarker.getId();
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}
```

And this is a sample where the Custom Dialog can only be called by adminmarker..

```
@Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
  AdminDialog adminDialog;

if (marker.getId().equals(PREVIOUS_ID)) {
    adminDialog = new AdminDialog();
    adminDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "custom-tag-goes-here");
    }
}
```